# ¿Por qué no reconoce la función this.dibujar en mi código?

Tags: javascript, funciones

Cuándo corro el código en el navegador la consola me dice:

"Uncaught TypeError: this.dibujar is not a function".

Código HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>DAIGHT</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="DAIGHT.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas width="600" height="600" id="c"></canvas>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            inicio();
        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Código Js:

```
var soloId, canvas;
var dinosaur;

var Imagen = function (u, x, y) {

    this.iURL = u;
    this.iOK = false;
    this.pos = [x, y];
    this.i;
    this.creari(this.i, this.iURL);
    this.dibujar;
    this.confirmar;
}

Imagen.prototype.creari = function (i, u) {

    i = new Image();
    i.src = u;
    i.onload = this.confirmar;
}

Imagen.prototype.confirmar = function ()
{
    if (this.iOK == false)
    {
        this.iOK = true;
    }

    this.dibujar(this.i);
}

Imagen.prototype.dibujar = function (i)
{
    if (this.iOK == true)
    {
        canvas.drawImage(i, this.pos[0], this.pos[1]);
    }
}

function inicio(){

    soloId = document.getElementById("c");
    canvas = soloId.getContext("2d");

    dinosaur = new Imagen("Dinosaur.png", 555, 555);

}
```

Muchas Gracias por su ayuda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uno de los problemas son estas líneas:

```
this.dibujar;
this.confirmar;
```

Si son funciones tienes que invocarlas usando paréntesis, así

```
this.dibujar();
this.confirmar();
```

Pero hay más problemas en tu código, te dejo un ejemplo de como podría ser:

```
var Imagen = function(canvas, url, x, y) {
    this.canvas = canvas;
    this.pos = {x, y};
    this.crearImagen(url);
}

Imagen.prototype.crearImagen = function(url) {
    var self = this;
    this.imagen = new Image();
    this.imagen.onload = function() {
        self.dibujar();
    };
    this.imagen.src = url;
}

Imagen.prototype.dibujar = function() {
    this.canvas.drawImage(this.imagen, this.pos.x, this.pos.y);
}

function inicio() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("c").getContext("2d");

    var dinosaur = new Imagen(canvas, "Dinosaur.png", 555, 555);
}

inicio();
```

Comment: Me gusta tu código, gracias. Podrías explicarme por qué creas la variable self en vez de poner directamente this?

Comment: Es que en JavaScript `this` tiene un comportamiento diferente a otros lenguajes.  En este caso cuando `onload` sea invocado puedes verificar con el debugger que `this` no es el objeto `Imagen` que esperarías por eso guardo una copia en la variable `self` (el nombre no tiene nada de especial)

Comment: Gracias otra vez, otra pregunta: Por qué para la posición de "x" y de "y" usas un objeto tipo JSON en vez de un array?

Comment: Bueno, eso es preferencia personal, es más clara la intención cuando lees `pos.x` que `pos[0]`.  Por cierto no es un objeto JSON, es un objeto regular de JavaScript.